# Why React doesn't use promise.resolve for batching updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, internals

Currently, React only batches updates in functions that are called by the React itself. like event handlers and lifecycles. And as far as I know, React simply calls these functions like they are wrapped in `unstable_batchedUpdates`.
Lets assume it's something like the following:

```js
unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
  instance.componentDidMount();
});
```

So right now, we have to manually wrap functions that are called by someone other than the React inside of the `unstable_batchedUpdates`.

I'm also aware that in the concurrent mode, we have the `updates train` concept and we batch all of the state updates together.

But I have two questions,
First, how does this `update train` works? What mechanism decides which updates should be on the train? Is it only the time of occurrence?
And second, Why it has to be this complicated? why we couldn't do something similar to what Vue does and wrap all of the `setState` calls inside of a nextTick function? I know it's almost similar to what we will have in the **concurrent mode**, but what kind of bottlenecks and problems do we have for adding it right now, without the **concurrent mode** enabled?

I'm thinking of starvation problem. But I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.